# SAPUI5 showing table-filter criteria to user

Tags: xml, filter, sapui5, sap-fiori

I have a simple SAPUI5 table with product data as content.

Now I want to show the current placed filter to the user like in the screenshot below.

The idea behind this is that the user can quickly recognize that the data that is shown in the table is filtered. Also the user should be able to remove the filter quickly.

Is there a feature on the table component to do this or do I have to programm something like this on my own way?

Any idea and help is appreciated :)

[image]

Comment: The smart- or normal filter bar comes to mind: https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/sdk#/entity/sap.ui.comp.smartfilterbar.SmartFilterBar/sample/sap.ui.comp.sample.smartfilterbar.example1

Comment: You can put this in the `extension` aggregation of a `sap.ui.table.Table`: https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/sdk#/entity/sap.m.Tokenizer/sample/sap.m.sample.Tokenizer

Comment: @Marc Thank you very much, this is exactly what I was searching for :)